# Where is python3 installed in macos?

Tags: python, macos

So, I've recently installed Anaconda with python 3.7.3. Even if it is a really neat way to access scientific libraries I still want access to the preinstalled python of macos Mojave. Whenever i type in terminal "python3" or "python3.7" the anaconda version pops up. the only way to access one of the preinstalled versions is to type "python2.7" which accesses python 2 not python 3.

After some navigation inside the filesystem I found that python 2 is in "/usr/bin".
Does anybody know where python 3 is located so that I can add to my .bash_profile something like "alias python3="[path]" ?

Comment: Are you sure there is a *Python 3* installed by default? Isn't there an */usr/bin/python3*?

Comment: Before installing Anaconda python 3.7.0 was installed by default. In /usr/bin/ I can only find python2

Comment: @ThanosTapras try command `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: "I still want access to the preinstalled python of macos Mojave" <- Only Python 2 (2.7.10) is preinstalled on macOS Mojave. There is no Python 3 version shipped with the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Python3 and I check by

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `$ which python3`
3. Result: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`

Comment: Thanks! Just added `alias python3 = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3"` to my .bash_profile and whenever I type python3 the default python comes up.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `which` command with `-a` [parameter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/which-command-in-linux-with-examples/) . It lists all the available paths.

```
$ which -a python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/other/path/to/python3
```

Comment: If I type "which python3" the result is "/Users/thanasis/anaconda3/bin/python3" because the command python3 is associated with the python version installed by anaconda

Comment: @ThanosTapras It list all the paths

Comment: I'm sorry, you have to pass `-a` parameter to list all available pythons. I will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ which -a python*
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python-config
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3-config
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3.10
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3.10-config
```

So I got at least python3 und python3.10, probably also python2, installed on my FireHD 10 tablet ...